# VBA IDE Icons *.svg *.ico

Tags: vba, excel, svg, icons

Can someone please tell me how I can get the VBA IDE icons **files** [pictured]

[image]

I have spent the last several hours trying to find a way to expose them via `FaceId` all the links I have found are either for making a ribbon or a form with the faces on there I just want the files.

Google wasn't my friend this time, even with the advanced search tools where you can specify the type as an icon

Comment: They are probably embedded in the `.exe` or some other resource file. You could try something like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/109347/extract-high-quality-icons-from-files-using-a-free-tool/)?

Comment: @Vegard thank you, if no one else can answer in a way I can do it via VBA then I guess you could answer with this and I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: This is possible via some Windows APIs, but would be a serious PITA because you either need to hard code the file paths or [find](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40962539/4088852) where they are installed on the machine.  There are examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?637452-vb6-Icon-Handle-to-File-Array) and [here](http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/e/extracticon.html). The first 3 icons live in vbe7.dll, and the 4th in excel.exe. No clue where the last one is loaded from.  I'd suspect one of the shared office dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the BeCyIconGrabber as detailed in the comment from @Vegard from [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/109347/extract-high-quality-icons-from-files-using-a-free-tool/)

Still took a while to find what I was after, I also found [this](http://soltechs.net/customui/imageMso01.asp?gal=4&count=no) which has some of the icons I was after.